# Hide AutoComplete box drop down in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I assigned the default value to auto complete box in page load event. If i assigned the default value the drop down opens with the assigned value. can anyone please help how to close the drop down in auto complete box

Answer (score 0):

Find below xaml code:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="SampleAutoCompleteBox.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleAutoCompleteBox"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <local:SampleWords
    x:Key="AutoCompletions" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Sample Auto Complete Box" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Example Page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="450" Grid.Row="0"                                    
                                 Name="autoCompleteBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="autoCompleteBox1_TextChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And below is the code of source code. Here I am setting `SelectedItem` of `AutoCompleteBox` on page start but not setting ItemSource in .xaml and on textChanged I am setting its Item source.

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private string defaultText;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        defaultText = "condimentum";

        autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem = defaultText;

    }

    private void autoCompleteBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchText = ((AutoCompleteBox)sender).SearchText;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) && !defaultText.Equals(searchText))
        {
            autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = SampleWords.AutoCompletions;
            autoCompleteBox1.TextChanged -= autoCompleteBox1_TextChanged;
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I tried but Autocomplete box doesn't show the default text.

Comment: I have created a sample for the same and it is working for me.. I have update complete xaml and complete C# code.. Now check if you are missing anything.

Comment: No. It doesn't works. i assigned the default text with a space at end. so the drop down don't appears if we assign.

Comment: My mistake I have moved autoCompleteBox1.ItemsSource = SampleWords.AutoCompletions; in autoCompleteBox1_TextChanged that will solve your problem.